# Constants across the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a $n$ x $n$ matrix $M$. It has spectra given by $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ with corresponding eigenvectors $u_1,...,u_n$.

Generally speaking, is there a quantity that is constant for all eigenvalue+eigenvector pairs?

In other words, is there some function that takes say $\lambda_1$ and $u_1$ as input, and outputs a number $C$. Take now $\lambda_n$ and $u_n$, apply the same function and it also outputs $C$.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. If your space is $U$ over a field $F$, take the function $f:F\times U\to \{0\}$ defined by $f(\lambda,u)=0$ for all pairs $(\lambda,u)\in F\times U$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post @MichaelMorrow. I guess I would be more curious to see if there are functions that send the inputs to non-zero constants. Would you happen to know about that?

Comment: Yeah. Just redefine $f:F\times U\to\{C\}$ as $f(\lambda,u)=C$ where $C$ is a nonzero constant.

Comment: Slightly more useful, though they yield constant vectors, not numbers: $f: F\times U\to U,~(\lambda,u)\mapsto (\lambda I_n-M)u$ will map a pair to $0$ if and only if it is a pair of eigenvector and eigenvalue.